SQL Loader ERROR - Physical record in data file (text.csv) is longer than the maximum(1048576)
I have a huge file (CSV) to load into Oracle approx,15gb, containing 50 million rows. Below is the error when I try to run sqlldr
Path used:     Direct
SQLLoader-510: Physical record in data file (text.csv) is longer than the maximum(1048576)
SQLLoader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.
Tried to use readsize = 3000000 and concatenate also. Nothing seems to work with this file and the same error always.
The control file like this:
options (skip=1,direct=true)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'text.csv'
BADFILE 'text.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'text.dsc'
INTO TABLE "user"."users_data"
insert
fields terminated by ',' Optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
refnum,
parentrefnum,
refcode,
class_code
full_address,
country,
city,
suburbs,
create_date,
update_date
)

Ensure your data has proper line terminator bytes at responsible intervals and SQLLoader is expecting that particular line termination.

As Paul suggested, a common cause here is platform inconsistencies. For example, if the file was generated on Unix and then you are running SQL Loader on Windows.  It will look for the Windows definition of end-of-line, which might not match Unix. Hence (from SQL Loader perspective) the lines go on "forever"
